# withCriteria two level deep association eager fetch grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'd like to eager load a structure, two levels deep in an association chain. Something along the lines of:

```
class TopLevel {
    String name

    LevelOne levelOne
}    

class LevelOne {
    String name

    LevelTwo levelTwo
}

class LevelTwo {
    String name
}
```

I'd like to load the entire structure. Searching around I found this example, but it didn't work. The "println" generated a query to the LevelTwo table.

```
def result = TopLevel.withCriteria {
    eq('name', 'test')
    fetchMode "levelOne", FetchMode.JOIN
    levelOne {
        fetchMode "levelTwo", FetchMode.JOIN
    }
}

println result.levelOne.levelTwo.name
```

Appreciate any help!
- Steve

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it working. Here's the secret sauce:

```
def result = TopLevel.withCriteria {
    eq('name', 'test')
    fetchMode 'levelOne', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'levelOne.levelTwo', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'levelOne.levelTwo.levelThree', FetchMode.JOIN
}
```