# How do I eager load the association class defined via joinTable in Grails?

Tags: grails, performance

In other words, the following:

```
class Subscriber { 
    ... 
    static hasMany = [ topics : Topic] 
    static fetchMode = [topics:"eager"] 

    static mapping = { 
        topics joinTable: [name: 'subscriber_topic', column: 'topic_id', key: 'subscriber_id']  
    } 
}
```

eagerly loads the join table subscriber_topic but not the Topic class as seen in sql logging:

```
Hibernate: 
    select 
        subscriber0_.id as id41_0_, 
        subscriber0_.version as version41_0_, 
        .... 
        topics2_.subscriber_id as subscriber1_3_, 
        topics2_.topic_id as topic2_3_ 
    from 
        subscriber subscriber0_ 
    left outer join 
        subscriber_topics topics2_ 
            on subscriber0_.id=topics2_.subscriber_id 
    where 
        subscriber0_.id=?
```

---

I'd expect the actual Topic objects fetched-- not the join table. But, appears fetching is happening at join table and not the actual associated objects.

Answer (score 0):

Although there might be no clear way to eager load associations using `joinTable` declaration in domain class yet, you may do the deep eager loading when the query is issued Criteria Builder (e.g., `withCriteria()`) as illustrated and answered by this question titled "[withCriteria two level deep association eager fetch grailsn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176121/withcriteria-two-level-deep-association-eager-fetch-)"